# How to make the Netbeans doesn't ask for the master password?

Tags: svn, netbeans, passwords

I (have to) use Netbeans for my work. The code is checked out from SVN and Netbeans offered to remember the username and password.

However, Netbeans ALWAYS asks for the master password when I open it. It is so annoying because this is my machine and I know what I am doing.

I work under Ubuntu 11.10 x64, and Netbeans 7.01. I tried to google the answer, and I have tried the solutions on http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqMasterPasswordDialog and it didn't work.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 8):

You can edit your netbeans.conf file by adding the following option:

-J-Dnetbeans.keyring.no.master=true

The netbeans.conf file is located in the "netbeans-install-dir"/etc directory

Comment: This "works", but NetBeans will give up to store passwords (FTP, git ...) out of the session. So, you suppress one "master pass" but a flood of other enter-password-dialogs will follow.

Answer (score 2):

When you're modifying your netbeans.conf, make sure that you actually add this line inside the quotes of the *netbeans_default_options=*, this foxed me for half an hour.

Answer (score 1):

The IDE asks for master password when fails to access the system-default-mechanism to store passwords and other secure data (as [explained here](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqMasterPasswordDialog)).
There are generally two ways to avoid it:

1. Run the IDE with *-J-Dnetbeans.keyring.no.master=true* (or place the command to *netbeans.conf*) But you are **losing a chance to store any passwords** (ftp, git, svn ...) out of the session. The master-password dialogue is gone, many others are on the way.
2. Configure the system for NetBeans to run the keyring properly. One possible solution is pointed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/416976/why-does-netbeans-ask-for-master-password-at-the-begining): Check if the library `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnome-keyring.so.0` exists and create the link NetBeans is looking for.

   ```
   cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
   ls libgnome-key*
   ...
   sudo ln -s libgnome-keyring.so.0 libgnome-keyring.so
   ```

   Try to install the lib if not present:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libgnome-keyring0
   ```

Comment: `libgnome-keyring0` does unfortunately not exist anymore in Ubuntu 20.04+. I suppose it's now just `gnome-keyring`. However, I'd used NB 12.4 and was able to solve this problem by installing the new NB 12.6. The problem does not seem to show up anymore now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with NetBeans 8.02. As it turns out, NetBeans is looking for an enviromental variable called GNOME_KEYRING_, no matter the value. So, I inserted this line at the beginning of the netbeans shell script in %netbeansinstalldir%/bin/netbeans

export GNOME_KEYRING_=foobar

Works like a charm.

Original post
https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=249287